# How can I check if there are no command line arguments passed in a busybox based Unix system?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line-arguments, busybox

I am trying to create a if else statement where if checks if there is a command line argument and else is for when there is none. I've tried it with if else and two ifs. Whenever I run without any argument I get the error:

*sh: 0: unknown operand*.

If I run with a command line argument it works fine.
If I run the script with `if $1` I get the error:

*sh: missing ]*

Here is the two cases I tried latest,

```
if [ $1 -gt 0 ];
then
    ch=$1
    stri=$2
    thefunction $ch $stri
fi

# User input not working

if [ -z "$1" ];
then
    stat="Y"
    while [ $stat == "[Yy]" ];
    do
        printf "\nPlease enter a choice. Enter 1 for manual.\n"
        read ch
        flag=1
        if [ $ch -eq 3];
        then
            printf "\nPlease enter string to be searched.\n"
            read stri
        fi
        thefunction $ch $stri $flag
        printf "Do you wanna continue? \n Press 'Y' to continue..."
        read stat
    done
fi
```

***and***

```
if [ $1 -gt 0 ];
then
    ch=$1
    stri=$2
    thefunction $ch $stri
else
    stat="Y"
    while [ $stat == "[Yy]" ];
    do
        printf "\nPlease enter a choice. Enter 1 for manual.\n"
        read ch
        flag=1
        if [ $ch -eq 3];
        then
            printf "\nPlease enter string to be searched.\n"
            read stri
        fi
        thefunction $ch $stri $flag
        printf "Do you wanna continue? \n Press 'Y' to continue..."
        read stat
    done
fi
```

I've also tried using multiple [[ ]] for of instead of single [ ], `if ! $1` and most of what I could find on Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I check if there are no command line arguments passed in a busybox based Unix system?

You check if the count of arguments is equal to zero.

```
if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then
   echo "No arguments passed"
fi
```

Without arguments the `$1` expands to nothing so:

```
if [ $1 -gt 0 ];
```

expands to:

```
if [ -gt 0 ];
```

As `-gt 0 ]` are invalid arguments for `[`, the tool complains.

Note that bash is space aware and `3];` is probably meant to be `3 ];`.

Also `[ $stat == "[Yy]" ]` checks if stat is equal to the string `"[Yy]"`. And the `==` is a extension for `[` command, use `=` instead. To check if `$stat` is equal to `Y` or `y`, use `[ "$stat" = "y" -o "$stat" = "Y" ]` or use a `case` construct.